# puppet exit code 2 while expecting 0 with rundeck

Tags: bash, puppet, exit-code, rundeck

I'm trying to run a task in rundeck that runs a "puppet agent -tod", but since puppet returns an exit code of 2, which means it applied some changes as seen on https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.2/man/agent.html at --detailed-exitcodes section, but rundeck all that is different from 0 marks it as failed. Can I force in some way to show a 0 exit code instead of 2?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run a modified command, such as

```
puppet agent -tod || test $? -eq 2
```

That supposes that rundeck will run it via the shell, of which I am uncertain.  If it wants a command it can execute directly then you could use

```
bash -c 'puppet agent -tod || test $? -eq 2'
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, that test command throws an exit code 0 when it is 2, so every other code(fail) will cause the command to throw an exit code 1 and it will be hadled by Rundeck, this is just great!!

Answer (score 0):

Checking it in the command list is a good idea. Another approach would be to use a step error handler and check the exit code there. Configure the error handler to keep going if exit code == 2.