# Handle exit code for server shutdown using Chef recipe and Rundeck

Tags: chef-infra, rundeck

I wrote a Chef recipe shutdown the server. Server gets shutdown, but the exit code is 1. I'm trying to use this recipe in Rundeck. Since the exit code is non zero, it is treated as failure in Rundeck orchestration.

I tried adding `returns` parameter, still same issue. Any suggestions please.

```rb
execute 'shutdown_server' do
  command 'shutdown -h now'
  returns [0,1,-1]
  action :run
end
```

Comment: Rundeck Jobs fail with any code different from 0, a good "workaround" is to wrap your deployment in a script that returns 0 on your condition.

Comment: You should be able to run the shutdown command directly from Rundeck. This can be done once Chef recipe completes execution.

Comment: Man page for `shutdown` shows `On success, 0 is returned`. Maybe a good idea to check why you are getting a non-zero return code.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck Jobs fail with any code other than zero. You should "wrap" your deployment in a Rundeck inline-script job that returns 0 for your specific condition. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34338630/10426011) answer.